# Why does the scrollbar influence width of fixed/absolute elements but not static/relative

Tags: html, macos, css, momentum

We noticed a strange behaviour with all browsers under OSX' when using the scrollbar "show automatically"-feature vs. "always visible" (see OSX settings->general).

If it's switched to "always", fixed/absolute elements with 100% are 15px less width than when switched to "automatically".

I can basically understand that the "always" scrollbar uses fixed space vs. the "automatic" scrollbar is some kind of overlaid over the content.

But why on earth does this matter to

```
position:fixed/absolute
```

elements, but not to

```
position:static/relative?
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate the problem, however, you'll have to switch your system settings to notice it:
https://jsfiddle.net/n4jtpwvw/

Desired end-result: the blue (#navigation) and red (#main) DIV should align perfectly, no matter the clients settings on scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with position fixed/absolute are generally taken out of the normal document flow. There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014687/830199) of what's going on behind the scenes.

As for your code, have a look at this updated jsfiddle, works for me when toggling that OSX option on and off

https://jsfiddle.net/n4jtpwvw/1/

```
.w1 {
  ...
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigationWrapper {
  ...
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

I set a max-width on .w1 and auto margins. Then I took out the left and right properties from #navigationWrapper and let it inherit the max-width from .w1

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this asap. Did you look at your fiddle on an iPhone? Strange things happen to "navigation" when scrolling back up...

Comment: I was able to adapt your code to the real HTML, thanks so much!

Comment: you're welcome! as for the iPhone, there's often some quirkiness going on when using fixed elements. One of the things I found useful to do is to remove the bounce effect when scrolling to the top of the page, in some cases it sort viewport's calculations out. [This](https://github.com/timbartsch/no-bounce) is a nice script.